# Extending custom classes and using them in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, nested, subclass

I'm just learning Java... I have 2 custom classes. One is a `Fraction` and another is a `Matrice` that uses `Fraction`.
I'm using Eclipse, and created both classes from scratch via `file->new->class` (and default settings).

I'm wondering how can I use these two together in my main program? Like, when I try to add the classes to my project (it was unsuccessful but also) the `Matrice` class broke.

I also put the `Fractions` class (.class and .java) in a higher hierarchy of directories with no success (put `Fractions` in `com.myfolder` and `Matrices` in `com.myfolder.myotherfolder` and specified `package com.myfolder` and `package com.myfolder.myotherfolder` respectively).

So really, I have no idea what I'm doing here. I'm doing Java on my own, so I get stuck on a lot of the things like this. My question is, how do I:

1. Make real classes I can use in the future (object classes or whatever you call them; like I would call a new instance of `Fraction`/`Matrice`),
2. Make custom classes that extend other custom classes,
3. Use my custom classes in a project.

I've googled it but had no luck. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you import the `Fraction` class in the `Matrice` (Matrix?) class?

Comment: Read the Java tutorial. Here's the part about packages: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html. Tell us the error messages that you have, and show us the code

Comment: Yes I imported it in the Matrice class, but Fraction was all in red and I had all these errors.

Thanks, I'll take a look at the packages

Comment: *I had all these errors* : **which** errors? Errors come with error messages, that are intended to be read, and have a meaning. Without reading the error messages and seeing the code, we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was clear that all these errors was refering to the Fractions underlined in red; ie they were not being imported/whatever properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Just write them and probably provide a custom constructor. Then create instances using the `new` keyword.

b) You used the correct keyword: extend(s):

```
 class MyCustomClassB extends MyCustomClassA { ... }
```

c) Make sure the classes are on the classpath and use the `import` keyword to import them into classes that use them and are not in the same package:

```
package com.myfolder.myotherfolder;

import com.myfolder.Fraction;

public class Matrice { ... }
```

Comment: So if I have Fraction and Matrice in com.folder.anotherfolder, both of them would start with 

    `package com.folder.anotherfolder`

and Matrice would additionally need 

    `import com.folder.anotherfolder.Fraction`
? Or would it be just `import Fraction` since they're both in the same directory?

Comment: @user1092951 the package is defined by the folder they're in, so you're right here. If both classes are in the same package you don't need to import them, as I said above. You only need to import classes that are not in the same package.

Comment: It worked once now I get errors again ("Fraction cannot be resolved/Fraction cannot be resolved to a type"). Matrice and Fraction are both in com.folder.anotherfolder and both are in packages in the package explorer.

Nevermind... it's working again.. I think I was editing the wrong .java or .class or something. thanks haha.

Both have the package declaration, I've tried using "import com.folder.anotherfolder.Fraction" and without the import, still get errors